# ¿Como enviar un mensaje del lado del cliente desde un botón que hace postback?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Hola espero puedan ayudar ya que no he podido solucionar esto de antemano muchas gracias.

Tengo una modal con datos que obtengo desde mi jqxgrid(jqwidgets), dentro de la modal tengo un botón para descargar un archivo de tipo excel, este botón hace postback completamente para poder descargar el archivo pero la modal no se cierra.

Al terminar de descargar el archivo quiero mostrar un mensaje dentro de la modal pero este no se muestra debido a que el botón hace postback completamente.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como mostrar el mensaje?

Gracias.

Este es mi código dentro de la modal.

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
 
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
   
   
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <h6>Sueldo</h6>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                <div class="row">                                   
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                      <div class="input-group-text text-dark">$</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <input id="txtSueldo" type="text" class="form-control"/>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <h6>Prestamo</h6>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                  <div class="row">                                    
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                         <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <div class="input-group-text text-dark">$</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input id="txtPrestamo" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <h6>Bono</h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="row">                                    
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="input-group"> 
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <div class="input-group-text text-dark">$</div>
                                            </div>                                         
                                            <input id="txtBono" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />                                
                                <div class="row">
                                   <div class="col-lg-12">
                                     <asp:Button ID="btn_descargar_archivo" runat="server" Text="Descargar Archivo" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block"  onclick="btn_descargar_archivo_Click" />                      
                                            </div>
                                        </div> 
                                        <br />
        <div class="row">
                                     <div class="col-lg-12">                                                   
                                        <div id="archivo_descargado_mensaje" class="p-3 mb-1 bg-success text-white text-center" style="display:none"> Archivo descargado con exito
          </div>                                                   
                                      </div>
                                  </div>                                 

      </div>   
   
   
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Este es mi código dentro del servidor el cual funciona correctamente solo quiero mostrar el mensaje en la modal.

```
protected void btn_descargar_archivo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string nombre_archivo = "Prueba.xlsx";
  string direccion = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Excel_file/" + nombre_archivo);

                System.IO.FileStream fs = null;

                fs = System.IO.File.Open(direccion, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
                byte[] btFile = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(btFile, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                fs.Close();                   

            // Aqui intento mostrar el mensaje pero este no se visualiza en la modal                    
            string visible_texto = @"$(""[id*='archivo_descargado_mensaje']"").css('display', 'block');";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "visible_texto_descarga", visible_texto, true);                 

                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nombre_archivo);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(btFile);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); 
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();    
 }
```

Comment: Lo que intentas hacer, **no se puede realizar** con un **Postback** al servidor, podrías hacerlo utilizando AJAX.

Comment: Hola @RafaelAcosta he colocado el código completo de la modal. También intente descargar el archivo por medio de ajax pero no pude ya que no me descarga el archivo aquí puede ver mi publicación https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188464/how-to-download-a-file-located-in-a-project-folder-using-ajax-and-webmethod

Answer (score 0):

prueba con llamar a tu codigo de esta manera:

el id para que lo tome el cliente debes definir que se mantenga en el cliente y no lo cambie agregando ClientIDMode="Static":

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_descargar_archivo" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Descargar Archivo" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="btn_descargar_archivo_Click" />
```

Luego registra el script que devolvera en el postback:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Mensaje", "mostrarMensaje();", true);
```

pon este codigo javascript donde esta el codigo del modal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mostrarMensaje() {
        $('#archivo_descargado_mensaje').show();
    }
</script>
```

referencia para  mas info y hacer pruebas minimas con ejemplos:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.8

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Hola @Fabiansilva he colocado el código como me sugieres lamentablemente sigue sin mostrar el mensaje.

Comment: prueba a ver si hay algo mal en el codigo... cambia a clientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Mensaje", "alert(test);", true); 
y ver si es que funciona registerStartupScript

Comment: Hola @Fabiansilva el mensaje sigue sin mostrarse y es debido por el postback del botón ya que este hace un postback completo para descargar el archivo y aunque la modal permanezca abierta no se muestra el mensaje. Tambien probe **ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this, typeof(Page), "visible_texto_excel", "mostrarMensaje();");** y **ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "visible_texto_excel", "mostrarMensaje();",true);** sin exito.

Comment: prueba llamar Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('test');", true);   en el page_load y ver si al arrancar la pagina muestra el alerta, luego pruebalo en el codigo del server para el boton

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar un mensaje de alerta utilice el siguiente código:

```
string mensaje = "<script>alert('Aquí el mensaje');</script>";
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "alert", mensaje, false);
```

Utilice el siguiente código con el fin de registrar el script dek modal después del postback

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Modal", "$('body').removeClass('modal-open');$('.modal-backdrop').remove();$('#nombreModal').hide();$('body').css('padding-right','0');", true);
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopupModal();", true);
```

Utilice esta función JavaScript, la cuál se encargará de abrir su Modal:

```
function ShowPopupModal() {
    $("#btnShowPopupModal").click();
}
```

Botón:

```
<button type="button" style="display: none;" id="btnShowPopupModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                                                                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nombreModal">
                                                                    Launch demo modal
                                                                </button>
```